# Failed to decode h264 key frame with DXVA2.0 because returned buffer is to small

Tags: ffmpeg, javacv, libav, dxva

I hava a strange problem on Windows with DXVA2 h264 decoding. I recently figured out a ffmpeg decoding limitation for DXVA2 and D3D11VA on Windows and how to [solve it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76189005/2298490), this solution completly fixes the problem with D3D11VA but DXVA2 still has some problems with certain keyframes. Upon further investigation it turned out that the decoding of these certain keyframes fail because the buffer returned from the [IDirectXVideoDecoder_GetBuffer](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/9d70e74d255dbe37af52b0efffc0f93fd7cb6103/libavcodec/dxva2.c#L817) function was too small. FFmpeg is printing out these logs when the decoding fails:

```
Error: [h264 @ 0000028b2e5796c0] Buffer for type 5 was too small. size: 58752, dxva_size: 55296
Error: [h264 @ 0000028b2e5796c0] Failed to add bitstream or slice control buffer
Error: [h264 @ 0000028b2e5796c0] hardware accelerator failed to decode picture
```

Why is this returned buffer too low? What kind of factors inside ffmpeg do have an effect on this buffer size or is this a limitation of DXVA2 in general? All other decoders like Cuvid, D3D11VA or the software decoder are not affected by this problem and can decode all keyframes.

I have an example javacv project on [github](https://github.com/grill2010/ExampleDXVA2) that can reproduce the problem. I also provide the source code of the main class here. The keyframe example data with prepended SPS and PPS in hex form can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IOViEDfav0sLAQ-cLcSZ_7HqK7iw93E3/view).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.avcodec.AVCodec;
import org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.avcodec.AVCodecContext;
import org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.avcodec.AVCodecHWConfig;
import org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.avcodec.AVPacket;
import org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.avutil.AVBufferRef;
import org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.avutil.AVDictionary;
import org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.avutil.AVFrame;
import org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.avutil.LogCallback;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.BytePointer;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.IntPointer;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.Pointer;
import org.tinylog.Logger;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

import static org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.avcodec.AVCodecContext.FF_THREAD_SLICE;
import static org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.global.avcodec.*;
import static org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.global.avutil.*;

public class App extends Application {

    /**** decoder variables ****/

    private AVHWContextInfo hardwareContext;

    private AVCodec decoder;
    private AVCodecContext m_VideoDecoderCtx;

    private AVCodecContext.Get_format_AVCodecContext_IntPointer formatCallback;

    private final int streamResolutionX = 1920;
    private final int streamResolutionY = 1080;

    // AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_CUDA // example works with cuda
    // AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_DXVA2 // producing Invalid data found on keyframe
    // AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_D3D11VA // producing Invalid data found on keyframe
    private static final int HW_DEVICE_TYPE = AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_DXVA2;

    private static final boolean USE_HW_ACCEL = true;

    private static final boolean USE_AV_EF_EXPLODE = true;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        //System.setProperty("prism.order", "d3d,sw");
        System.setProperty("prism.vsync", "false");
        Application.launch(App.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
        final Pane dummyPane = new Pane();
        dummyPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black");
        final Scene scene = new Scene(dummyPane, this.streamResolutionX, this.streamResolutionY);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(480);
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(360);

        this.initializeFFmpeg(result -> {
            if (!result) {
                Logger.error("FFmpeg could not be initialized correctly, terminating program");
                System.exit(1);
                return;
            }
            scene.setRoot(new StackPane());
            this.performTestFramesFeeding();
        });
    }

    private void initializeFFmpeg(final Consumer<Boolean> finishHandler) {
        FFmpegLogCallback.setLevel(AV_LOG_DEBUG); // Increase log level until the first frame is decoded
        FFmpegLogCallback.set();
        Pointer pointer = new Pointer((Pointer) null);
        AVCodec c;
        while ((c = av_codec_iterate(pointer)) != null) {
            if (av_codec_is_decoder(c) > 0)
                Logger.debug("{}:{} ", c.name().getString(), c.type());
        }

        this.decoder = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264); // usually decoder name is h264 and without hardware support it's yuv420p otherwise nv12
        if (this.decoder == null) {
            Logger.error("Unable to find decoder for format {}", "h264");
            finishHandler.accept(false);
            return;
        }
        Logger.info("Current decoder name: {}, {}", this.decoder.name().getString(), this.decoder.long_name().getString());

        if (true) {
            for (; ; ) {
                this.m_VideoDecoderCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(this.decoder);
                if (this.m_VideoDecoderCtx == null) {
                    Logger.error("Unable to find decoder for format AV_CODEC_ID_H264");
                    if (this.hardwareContext != null) {
                        this.hardwareContext.free();
                        this.hardwareContext = null;
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                if (App.USE_HW_ACCEL) {
                    this.hardwareContext = this.createHardwareContext();
                    if (this.hardwareContext != null) {
                        Logger.info("Set hwaccel support");
                        this.m_VideoDecoderCtx.hw_device_ctx(this.hardwareContext.hwContext()); // comment to disable hwaccel
                    }
                } else {
                    Logger.info("Hwaccel manually disabled");
                }

                // Always request low delay decoding
                this.m_VideoDecoderCtx.flags(this.m_VideoDecoderCtx.flags() | AV_CODEC_FLAG_LOW_DELAY);

                // Allow display of corrupt frames and frames missing references
                this.m_VideoDecoderCtx.flags(this.m_VideoDecoderCtx.flags() | AV_CODEC_FLAG_OUTPUT_CORRUPT);
                this.m_VideoDecoderCtx.flags2(this.m_VideoDecoderCtx.flags2() | AV_CODEC_FLAG2_SHOW_ALL);

                if (App.USE_AV_EF_EXPLODE) {
                    // Report decoding errors to allow us to request a key frame
                    this.m_VideoDecoderCtx.err_recognition(this.m_VideoDecoderCtx.err_recognition() | AV_EF_EXPLODE);
                }

                // Enable slice multi-threading for software decoding
                if (this.m_VideoDecoderCtx.hw_device_ctx() == null) { // if not hw accelerated
                    this.m_VideoDecoderCtx.thread_type(this.m_VideoDecoderCtx.thread_type() | FF_THREAD_SLICE);
                    this.m_VideoDecoderCtx.thread_count(2/*AppUtil.getCpuCount()*/);
                } else {
                    // No threading for HW decode
                    this.m_VideoDecoderCtx.thread_count(1);
                }

                this.m_VideoDecoderCtx.width(this.streamResolutionX);
                this.m_VideoDecoderCtx.height(this.streamResolutionY);
                this.m_VideoDecoderCtx.pix_fmt(this.getDefaultPixelFormat());

                this.formatCallback = new AVCodecContext.Get_format_AVCodecContext_IntPointer() {
                    @Override
                    public int call(final AVCodecContext context, final IntPointer pixelFormats) {
                        final boolean hwDecodingSupported = context.hw_device_ctx() != null && App.this.hardwareContext != null;
                        final int preferredPixelFormat = hwDecodingSupported ?
                                App.this.hardwareContext.hwConfig().pix_fmt() :
                                context.pix_fmt();
                        int i = 0;
                        while (true) {
                            final int currentSupportedFormat = pixelFormats.get(i++);
                            System.out.println("Supported pixel formats " + currentSupportedFormat);
                            if (currentSupportedFormat == AV_PIX_FMT_NONE) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        i = 0;
                        while (true) {
                            final int currentSupportedFormat = pixelFormats.get(i++);
                            if (currentSupportedFormat == preferredPixelFormat) {
                                Logger.info("[FFmpeg]: pixel format in format callback is {}", currentSupportedFormat);
                                return currentSupportedFormat;
                            }
                            if (currentSupportedFormat == AV_PIX_FMT_NONE) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        i = 0;
                        while (true) { // try again and search for yuv
                            final int currentSupportedFormat = pixelFormats.get(i++);
                            if (currentSupportedFormat == AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P) {
                                Logger.info("[FFmpeg]: Not found in first match so use {}", AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P);
                                return currentSupportedFormat;
                            }
                            if (currentSupportedFormat == AV_PIX_FMT_NONE) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        i = 0;
                        while (true) { // try again and search for nv12
                            final int currentSupportedFormat = pixelFormats.get(i++);
                            if (currentSupportedFormat == AV_PIX_FMT_NV12) {
                                Logger.info("[FFmpeg]: Not found in second match so use {}", AV_PIX_FMT_NV12);
                                return currentSupportedFormat;
                            }
                            if (currentSupportedFormat == AV_PIX_FMT_NONE) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        Logger.info("[FFmpeg]: pixel format in format callback is using fallback {}", AV_PIX_FMT_NONE);
                        return AV_PIX_FMT_NONE;
                    }
                };
                this.m_VideoDecoderCtx.get_format(this.formatCallback);

                final AVDictionary options = new AVDictionary(null);
                final int result = avcodec_open2(this.m_VideoDecoderCtx, this.decoder, options);
                if (result < 0) {
                    Logger.error("avcodec_open2 was not successful");
                    finishHandler.accept(false);
                    return;
                }
                av_dict_free(options);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (this.decoder == null || this.m_VideoDecoderCtx == null) {
            finishHandler.accept(false);
            return;
        }
        finishHandler.accept(true);
    }

    private AVHWContextInfo createHardwareContext() {
        AVHWContextInfo result = null;
        for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
            final AVCodecHWConfig config = avcodec_get_hw_config(this.decoder, i);
            if (config == null) {
                break;
            }

            if ((config.methods() & AV_CODEC_HW_CONFIG_METHOD_HW_DEVICE_CTX) < 0) {
                continue;
            }
            final int device_type = config.device_type();
            if (device_type != App.HW_DEVICE_TYPE) {
                continue;
            }
            final AVBufferRef hw_context = av_hwdevice_ctx_alloc(device_type);
            if (hw_context == null || av_hwdevice_ctx_create(hw_context, device_type, (String) null, null, 0) < 0) {
                Logger.error("HW accel not supported for type {}", device_type);
                av_free(config);
                av_free(hw_context);
            } else {
                Logger.info("HW accel created for type {}", device_type);
                result = new AVHWContextInfo(config, hw_context);
            }
            break;
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        this.releaseNativeResources();
    }

    /*****************************/
    /*** test frame processing ***/
    /*****************************/
    
    private void performTestFramesFeeding() {
        final AVPacket pkt = av_packet_alloc();
        if (pkt == null) {
            return;
        }
        try (final BytePointer bp = new BytePointer(65_535 * 15)) {


            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                final byte[] frameData = AVTestFrames.h264KeyTestFrame;

                bp.position(0);

                bp.put(frameData);
                bp.limit(frameData.length);

                pkt.data(bp);
                pkt.capacity(bp.capacity());
                pkt.size(frameData.length);
                pkt.position(0);
                pkt.limit(frameData.length);
                //pkt.flags(AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY);
                final AVFrame avFrame = av_frame_alloc();
                System.out.println("frameData.length " + frameData.length);

                final int err = avcodec_send_packet(this.m_VideoDecoderCtx, pkt); //fill_scaling_lists
                if (err < 0) {
                    final BytePointer buffer = new BytePointer(512);
                    av_strerror(err, buffer, buffer.capacity());
                    final String string = buffer.getString();
                    System.out.println("Error on decoding test frame " + err + " message " + string);
                    av_frame_free(avFrame);
                    return;
                }

                final int result = avcodec_receive_frame(this.m_VideoDecoderCtx, avFrame);
                final AVFrame decodedFrame;
                if (result == 0) {
                    if (this.m_VideoDecoderCtx.hw_device_ctx() == null) {
                        decodedFrame = avFrame;
                        System.out.println("SUCESS with SW decoding");
                    } else {
                        final AVFrame hwAvFrame = av_frame_alloc();
                        if (av_hwframe_transfer_data(hwAvFrame, avFrame, 0) < 0) {
                            System.out.println("Failed to transfer frame from hardware");
                            av_frame_unref(hwAvFrame);
                            decodedFrame = avFrame;
                        } else {
                            av_frame_unref(avFrame);
                            decodedFrame = hwAvFrame;
                            System.out.println("SUCESS with HW decoding");
                        }
                    }

                    av_frame_unref(decodedFrame);
                } else {
                    final BytePointer buffer = new BytePointer(512);
                    av_strerror(result, buffer, buffer.capacity());
                    final String string = buffer.getString();
                    System.out.println("error " + result + " message " + string);
                    av_frame_free(avFrame);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (pkt.stream_index() != -1) {
                av_packet_unref(pkt);
            }
            pkt.releaseReference();
        }
    }

    final Object releaseLock = new Object();
    private volatile boolean released = false;

    private void releaseNativeResources() {
        if (this.released) {
            return;
        }
        this.released = true;
        synchronized (this.releaseLock) {
            // Close the video codec
            if (this.m_VideoDecoderCtx != null) {
                avcodec_free_context(this.m_VideoDecoderCtx);
                this.m_VideoDecoderCtx = null;
            }

            // close the format callback
            if (this.formatCallback != null) {
                this.formatCallback.close();
                this.formatCallback = null;
            }

            // close hw context
            if (this.hardwareContext != null) {
                this.hardwareContext.free();
            }
        }
    }

    private int getDefaultPixelFormat() {
        return AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P; // Always return yuv420p here
    }


    /*********************/
    /*** inner classes ***/
    /*********************/

    public static final class HexUtil {

        private HexUtil() {
        }

        public static byte[] unhexlify(final String argbuf) {
            final int arglen = argbuf.length();
            if (arglen % 2 != 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Odd-length string");
            } else {
                final byte[] retbuf = new byte[arglen / 2];

                for (int i = 0; i < arglen; i += 2) {
                    final int top = Character.digit(argbuf.charAt(i), 16);
                    final int bot = Character.digit(argbuf.charAt(i + 1), 16);
                    if (top == -1 || bot == -1) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Non-hexadecimal digit found");
                    }

                    retbuf[i / 2] = (byte) ((top << 4) + bot);
                }

                return retbuf;
            }
        }
    }

    public static final class AVHWContextInfo {
        private final AVCodecHWConfig hwConfig;
        private final AVBufferRef hwContext;

        private volatile boolean freed = false;

        public AVHWContextInfo(final AVCodecHWConfig hwConfig, final AVBufferRef hwContext) {
            this.hwConfig = hwConfig;
            this.hwContext = hwContext;
        }

        public AVCodecHWConfig hwConfig() {
            return this.hwConfig;
        }

        public AVBufferRef hwContext() {
            return this.hwContext;
        }

        public void free() {
            if (this.freed) {
                return;
            }
            this.freed = true;
            av_free(this.hwConfig);
            av_free(this.hwContext);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            AVHWContextInfo that = (AVHWContextInfo) o;
            return freed == that.freed && Objects.equals(hwConfig, that.hwConfig) && Objects.equals(hwContext, that.hwContext);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(hwConfig, hwContext, freed);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "AVHWContextInfo[" +
                    "hwConfig=" + this.hwConfig + ", " +
                    "hwContext=" + this.hwContext + ']';
        }
    }

    public static final class AVTestFrames {

        private AVTestFrames() {

        }

        static {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = AVTestFrames.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("h264_test_key_frame.txt");
                final byte[] h264TestFrameBuffer = inputStream == null ? new byte[0] : inputStream.readAllBytes();
                final String h264TestFrame = new String(h264TestFrameBuffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                AVTestFrames.h264KeyTestFrame = HexUtil.unhexlify(h264TestFrame);
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                Logger.error(e, "Could not parse test frame");
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        inputStream.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Logger.error(e, "Could not close test frame input stream");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static byte[] h264KeyTestFrame;
    }

    public static class FFmpegLogCallback extends LogCallback {

        private static final org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.Logger logger = org.bytedeco.javacpp.tools.Logger.create(FFmpegLogCallback.class);

        static final FFmpegLogCallback instance = new FFmpegLogCallback().retainReference();

        public static FFmpegLogCallback getInstance() {
            return instance;
        }

        /**
         * Calls {@code avutil.setLogCallback(getInstance())}.
         */
        public static void set() {
            setLogCallback(getInstance());
        }

        /**
         * Returns {@code av_log_get_level()}.
         **/
        public static int getLevel() {
            return av_log_get_level();
        }

        /**
         * Calls {@code av_log_set_level(level)}.
         **/
        public static void setLevel(int level) {
            av_log_set_level(level);
        }

        @Override
        public void call(int level, BytePointer msg) {
            switch (level) {
                case AV_LOG_PANIC, AV_LOG_FATAL, AV_LOG_ERROR -> logger.error(msg.getString());
                case AV_LOG_WARNING -> logger.warn(msg.getString());
                case AV_LOG_INFO -> logger.info(msg.getString());
                case AV_LOG_VERBOSE, AV_LOG_DEBUG, AV_LOG_TRACE -> logger.debug(msg.getString());
                default -> {
                    assert false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: DXVA2 uses your graphics hardware to decode.  Evidently, your graphics hardware in memory-limited.

Comment: @TimRoberts I was able to reproduce the problem on two different PCs with two different graphics cards. On my main dev PC I have an Nvidea GeForce RTX 2080 Ti which should be capable of decoding a full HD h264 keyframe. Furthermore other hw decoders on my system (cuvid, D3D11VA) don't have this problem.